# How do I type a subscript of lowercase d into Quizlet?

Tags: unicode, character, copy-paste, glyphicons

So I've tried several things so far. I thought I finally had it when I tried copying and pasting unicode glyphs into quizlet, only to find out that the letter I needed (lowercase d) was missing from unicode! Does anyone have any ideas of how I can accomplish typing subscripts of letters such as lowercase d into Quizlet?